# jquery().trigger method to simulate click doesn't work but nativeElement.click does

Tags: angular6, angular-test

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
  <h4 *ngIf="username">A previous session already exists. Please re-enter password for {{username}} or click <a #cancelLink id="cancel-signin-link" href="#" (click)="redirectToNextComponent()">here</a> to sign out and go to the Homepage</h4>
</div>

    <div class="flex-container">
      <!--
      app login form is child of validate session here. One of the ways to commuicate from child to parent is to
      emit event from child and handle it in parent. Note that the event emitter name in child is used here i.e.
      app-login-form has @Output() formOutputEvent: EventEmitter<LoginFormValues>;
      -->
      <app-login-form #loginForm (formOutputEvent)="handleFormValues($event)" [userId]="username"></app-login-form>
    </div>
```

I want to simulate clicking the `<a>` in my test. I tried to use jQuery `trigger` but that doesn't seem to work. But if I use `nativeElement.click()` then the test case passes. Why is `jquery.trigger` not working?

Doesn't work

```
fit('should send signout request if user decides to cancel signin using id from existing session',()=>{
    let userService:UserManagementService = TestBed.get(UserManagementService);
    spyOn(userService,'onUserSignout');
    //expect(component.cancelLoginLink).toBeTruthy();
    expect($("#cancel-signin-link")).toBeTruthy();
    $("#cancel-signin-link").trigger("click");
    //component.cancelLoginLink.nativeElement.click();
    expect(userService.onUserSignout).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But this works

```
fit('should send signout request if user decides to cancel signin using id from existing session',()=>{
    let userService:UserManagementService = TestBed.get(UserManagementService);
    spyOn(userService,'onUserSignout');
    expect(component.cancelLoginLink).toBeTruthy();
    //expect($("#cancel-signin-link")).toBeTruthy();
    //$("#cancel-signin-link").trigger("click");
    component.cancelLoginLink.nativeElement.click();
    expect(userService.onUserSignout).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I also noticed that if I use jQuery then even this expectation passes `expect($("#cancel-signin-lk")).toBeTruthy();` (WRONG ID NAME).